# Installing requirement.txt file failing subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm a python newbie trying to install this repo locally - https://github.com/TrustworthyComputing/Fourier-Fingerprint-Search

Running the `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` renders the following error

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['pyfftw', 'include'].

      To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
      setuptools will not proceed with this build.

      If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
      on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
      Instead, consider the following options:

      1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
      2. use a `src-layout`
      3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names

      To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I read that I should add the following in my pyproject.toml file but to no avail

```
[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = []
```